# Replace all occurrences of string only if they don't start by '@'

Tags: c#, regex, string, regular-language

I would like to replace all the occurrences of a string, as long as those don't start by '@', so for example in the following query:

```
 (surname = @surname and surname = @surname1)
```

if I want to replace `surname`, it will only replace the two of them on the left side of the equal sign. Thus, leaving `@surname` and `@surname1` unreplaced.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Regex.Replace` for this:

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, "([^@])surname", "$1Diaz");
```

The `[^@]` basically tells Regex that any character except the @ symbol can come in front of the "surname" text that you are looking for.  The $1 is necessary because otherwise, whatever character that is will also get stripped out.

Note that this Regex, without some additional modification, will not match "surname" if it is at the beginning of the string.  In the example you provided, it starts with an open-parenthesis, so as long as that condition holds, the solution above will work.

Comment: You can also use zero-width assertions to eliminate the need of `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for this, how can it be modified to match "surname" at the beginning of the string too?